# Create instance of Spring´s ParameterizedTypeReference in Kotlin

Tags: spring-boot, generics, kotlin, spring-test

I am trying to learn Kotlin, and test how it works with spring boot. My application is using a mongo database to store data and I have a Jersey resource for retrieving data. I am testing it using `spring-boot-test` and `RestTestTemplate`.

The `RestTestTemplate` has an `exchange` method which takes a `ParameterizedTypeReference`. This class has a protected constructor. So the only way I managed to use it from Kotlin was like this:

`class ListOfPeople : ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Person>>()`

Here is my test-method:

```
@Test
fun `get list of people`() {
    // create testdata
    datastore.save(Person(firstname = "test1", lastname = "lastname1"))
    datastore.save(Person(firstname = "test2", lastname = "lastname2"))
    datastore.save(Person(firstname = "test3", lastname = "lastname2"))
    datastore.save(Person(firstname = "test4", lastname = "lastname2"))

    val requestEntity = RequestEntity<Any>(HttpMethod.GET, URI.create("/person"))

    // create typereference for response de-serialization
    class ListOfPeople : ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Person>>() // can this be done inline in the exchange method?
    val responseEntity : ResponseEntity<List<Person>> = restTemplate.exchange(requestEntity, ListOfPeople())

    assertNotNull(responseEntity)
    assertEquals(200, responseEntity.statusCodeValue)
    assertTrue( responseEntity.body.size >= 4 )

    responseEntity.body.forEach { person ->
        println("Found person: [${person.firstname} ${person.lastname}] " +
                ", born [${person.birthdate}]")
    }
}
```

Is this the correct (or only) way to do this, or is there a better way?

If it helps, here is a link for the whole test: [testclass on github](https://github.com/thomasandersen77/learning-kotlin/blob/master/kotlin-springboot/src/test/kotlin/org/andtho/kotlin/web/restkotlin/RestKotlinApplicationTests.kt)

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/nested-classes.html#anonymous-inner-classes

Comment: Thanks! I had read that earlier today, but couldn´t get it to work. Tried it now and this: restTemplate.exchange(requestEntity, object: ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Person>> () {}) worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

While the answer using object expression is correct and the direct equivalent of the way you do it in Java, reified type parameters allow you to simplify it if you need many `ParameterizedTypeReference`s:

```
inline fun <reified T> typeReference() = object : ParameterizedTypeReference<T>() {}

// called as
restTemplate.exchange(requestEntity, typeReference<List<Person>>())
```

When the compiler sees a `typeReference<SomeType>` call, it's replaced by the definition, so the result is the same as if you wrote `object : ParameterizedTypeReference<SomeType>() {}`.

Comment: Thanks. I accept this answer as I consider it better. I can absolutely see use-cases when I would need more than one :)

Answer (score 10):

Thanks to JB Nizet who pointed me to the correct documentation.

```
val responseEntity : ResponseEntity<List<Person>> =
            restTemplate.exchange(requestEntity, 
            object: ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Person>> () {})
```

If I read correctly this is called an Object expression.

Comment: Thank you, but still doesn't work for me. The inner model (here: Person) is just parsed as a LinkedHashMap for some reason.