# Nested reified parameter not working to create a ParameterizedTypeReference

Tags: spring, generics, kotlin, kotlin-reified-type-parameters

I have the following inline function with a reified parameter to generalize an http resource get:

```
inline fun <reified N> getResources(): ResponseEntity<List<N>> {
    val httpEntity = HttpEntity(null, httpHeaders)
    val resourceStr = getResourceString<N>()
    return rest.exchange(testContext.baseUrl + "/api/v1/$resourceStr", HttpMethod.GET,
            httpEntity, typeRef<List<N>>())
}
```

And I am building the `ParameterizedTypeReference` with a `typeRef` support function as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52581729/create-instance-of-spring%C2%B4s-parameterizedtypereference-in-kotlin):

```
inline fun <reified T : Any> typeRef(): ParameterizedTypeReference<T>{
    return object : ParameterizedTypeReference<T>() {}
}
```

When calling `getResources<Employee>()`, the `ParameterizedTypeReference` which is built has `ParameterizedTypeReference.type.actualTypeArguments` containing `java.util.List<? extends N>` instead of `java.util.List<Employee>`.

Notice that I am passing `typeRef<List<N>>`, where N is reified, from `getResources()` to the reified type T expected by `typeRef()` but it doesn't seem to be able to build its type properly.

Why isn't this working? Any work around?

**UPDATE:**

I've refactored the code to directly build the `ParameterizedTypeReference`in the first inline function but I'm still getting it as `java.util.List<? extends N>`.

```
private inline fun <reified N> getResources(): ResponseEntity<List<N>> {
    val httpEntity = HttpEntity(null, httpHeaders)
    val resourceStr = getResourceString<N>()
    return rest.exchange(testContext.baseUrl + "/api/v1/$resourceStr", HttpMethod.GET,
            httpEntity, object : ParameterizedTypeReference<List<N>>() {})
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems Kotlin doesn't support using reified parameters as generic types.

To work around this I have used Guava to generate a Type object and manually build the ParameterizedTypeReference:

```
private fun <T : Any> listTypeRef(clazz: Class<T>): ParameterizedTypeReference<List<T>> {
    val type = TypeToken.of(clazz).type
    val make = ParameterizedTypeImpl.make(List::class.java, arrayOf(type), null)
    return ParameterizedTypeReference.forType<T>(make) as ParameterizedTypeReference<List<T>>
}
```

Then I just use it in the getResources() function passing the java class of the nested type (S::class.java):

```
inline fun <reified S : Any> getResources(): ResponseEntity<List<S>> {
    val httpEntity = HttpEntity(null, httpHeaders)
    val resourceStr = getResourceString<S>(null)
    return rest.exchange(testContext.baseUrl + "/api/v1/$resourceStr", HttpMethod.GET,
            httpEntity, listTypeRef(S::class.java))
}
```