# spring kotlin restTemplate - how to parse JSON array inside response

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, resttemplate, spring-resttemplate

I keep struggling with parsing response represented by a JSON array into a data class entity using **Spring** with **Kotlin** and **RestTemplate**. Non-array like responses are without an issue, ie. the following is just enough to work as expected:

```
// JSON response - parsed correctly { data: { items: [{foo: 1}, {foo: 2}]

data class SomeData(val items: List<Item>)
data class NonArrayDataClass(val data: SomeData)

return restTemplate.client.postForEntity(
            url,
            request,
            NonArrayDataClass::class.java
        )
} }
```

But if the response is directly an array, I do not know how to bind into the target entity, ie:

```
// JSON response - not parsed correctly { [ {foo: 1}, {foo: 2} ] }

data class SomeData(val items: List<Items>)
data class ArrayDataClass(val data: SomeData) // no *data* key inside response

return restTemplate.client.postForEntity(
            url,
            request,
            // WHAT TO DO HERE? -> ArrayDataClass
        )
```

A Data class (*ArrayDataClass*) cannot be directly a list/array and there is no root key inside the response (aka *data*) to bind the list to as in the first working example above, it is directly an array.

Comment: try `restTemplate.postForEntity(..., Array<YOUR_CLASS>::class.java)` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39679180/kotlin-call-java-method-with-classt-argument

Comment: Would there be an elegant solution for Map<K, V> as well? Currently restTemplate/IDE complains with "Only classes are allowed on the left hand side of a class literal".

Comment: perhaps this works... `restTemplate.exchange(..., object: ParameterizedTypeReference<Map<KEY_CLASS, VAL_CLASS>> () {})` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52581729/create-instance-of-spring%C2%B4s-parameterizedtypereference-in-kotlin

Answer (score 0):

If you are completely sure about content in response, you can just write this:

```
val itemList = RestTemplate().postForEntity(
        url,
        request,
        List::class.java
    ).body as List<Item>
```

p.s. Your second json

> {[{"foo":1},{"foo":2}]}

is not valid json:). Only your first one, or this

> {"items":[{"foo":1},{"foo":2}]}

or this (code I suggested is suitable for this example)

> [{"foo":1},{"foo":2}]